# PHP create array from loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php function I am trying to create that will loop over a list of statuses in the database and then return an array of the data.

```
// Global function used to get the status types
function getStatusTypes(){

    // Array
    $statusTypes = array();

    // Get a list of the status types
    $objDB = new DB;
    $degreeStatuses = $objDB    
        -> setStoredProc('tuitionFetchStatuses')            
        -> execStoredProc()
        -> parseXML();

    // Put all of the values into an array
    foreach($degreeStatuses->data as $data){
        $statusTypes[] = array($data->statusID => $data->status);
    }

    // Return the array
    return $statusTypes;

}
```

I get this error: Warning: Illegal offset type Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) [3] => Array ( ) )

Anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: this code couldn't be producing that error, since you're not accessing any array elements in it - just building an array.

Comment: `print_r(getStatusTypes());` - I thought this would show me the array.

Comment: $data->statusID could be undefined

Comment: @Sunand Even if StatusID is null, PHP Should default to inserting integer indexes as a failsafe

Comment: status id is in fact being output

Comment: I had to add (int) before the statusID `$statusTypes[] = array((int)$data->statusID => $data->status);`